# Does Apple Reject applications that use a lot of bandwidth?

Tags: iphone, video

I've heard reports that Apple will reject applications that use excessive amounts of bandwidth.  The number that I've heard is a maximum of `1MB/minute` of bandwidth usage.  Although I've seen this number on various boards, I haven't been able to find an explicit statement from Apple's guidelines that speak to this.

I'm looking to stream video to an application and want to know what the maximum encoding rate of the videos should be.

Does anyone know what the exact number is?  Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3):

There is no published limit, I believe Apple leaves themselves some room to make a judgement about individual apps.

Keep in mind that you'll probably need to limit the bandwidth you use over cell anyways, since Edge is rather slow.  There is no limit on WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know of any specification regarding this topic. But yes, Apple will reject Applications which use a lot of bandwidth. You can restrict your application to WiFi only, then bandwidth usage is not a problem to Apple anymore. They have contracts with the mobile network operators to restrict the bandwith within their networks.

Answer (score 0):

1 mb/minute tested over five minutes seems to be the test.

Please see this other question for advice on this:

[iPhone app rejected for "transferring excessive volumes of data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236788/iphone-app-rejected-for-transferring-excessive-volumes-of-data)

This is also confirmed by Brian Stormont:

http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/04/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from.html