# XML, images, streaming video and "excessive volumes of data"

Tags: iphone, app-store, streaming, appstore-approval

My first application was submitted to App Store and failed to be approved owing to "excessive volumes of data over the cellular network". I don't know how they test this but since it's basically a news application which displays various articles, images and streamed videos, I would go and blame the videos for the rejection. I can't test it for sure because there is no network stats in Ipod Touch and that's the only device I can access.

And so I'm curious..

1) Does anyone have any idea how Apple "runs" bandwidth test?

2) What are ways I can improve my XML loading, image displaying and video streaming to reduce bandwidth (in case user uses cellular network)? For images, I use asynchronous loading (maybe that can be a problem if lots of images can be requested at the same time?) I'm looking at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ which could help with XML and maybe image loading but I don't understand if I can use ASIHTTPRequest to stream a video.

3) Is there any way to test network usage in iPhone simulator?

Comment: Could you limit it to wifi only?

Comment: If I would know that videos are exactly the problem - I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the streaming video is the problem. Apple want you to use [HTTP Live Streaming](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) if you want to stream video over the cellular network.

See [question 1236788](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236788/iphone-app-rejected-for-transferring-excessive-volumes-of-data) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

They run bandwidth tests by looking at byte counters for the network interface I think. You can do the same in the simulator by making sure no other networking apps are running on your mac and then look at the output of the 'netstat -i -b' command. Or use a fancy utility to monitor bandwidth usage.

Not helpful, but I'd like to say this anyway: Apple's claims are silly in my opinion. Why do they care.

Comment: I've heard that they have to care because of contracts with cellular network providers, but, anyway, I would love if they'd be more specific when rejecting applications.