# I'm implement http live streaming video from my webserver to iPhone. Will I get rejected for bandwidth?

Tags: iphone, http, video, stream, live

**Apache webserver setup**

added:

```
AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
AddType video/MP2T .ts
```

to "httpd.conf" file.

**Movie file preparation**

- I have 3 movie files (9mb - 25mb each).
- Used QuickTime to convert movies into iPhone format.
- Used mediafilesegmenter to convert .m4v into 10-second segments of .ts files, with an accompanying .m3u8 file.
- Placed these in a folder on webserver.

**iPhone App implementation**

- Created UIWebView whose URL points to http://71.190.235.29/~yujean/stream.html
- Simulator accesses the site and streams the movie-files just fine.

**Question**

- Will I still get rejected by apple for bandwidth issues over the 3G and/or Edge network?
- Do I need to somehow check which network the end-user is on first?  And then provide a different movie accordingly?  If so, how do I do that ...?

Thank you in advance,

Eugene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We were rejected when we first submitted our mp3 streamer to the app store for excessive bandwidth use.  Then we hobbled the app to limit its downloads to 4.5 meg in 5 min, which was accepted by Apple.

You can [review that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236788/iphone-app-rejected-for-transferring-excessive-volumes-of-data) for more info on the issue.

Comment: How did you "hobble" your app?  By simply lowering the quality of your mp3's?

I heard that using AAC-format + mono significantly reduces files size while avoiding extreme loss in sound quality.

Comment: Matt Gallagher at Cocoa with Love blog wrote us some custom code 

http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/03/streaming-mp3aac-audio-again.html and specific to throttling here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/04/network-data-requirements-on-iphone-os.html

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second bullet-point first, the SDK does that all for you. Determining what quality to stream is not the concern of the developer.

To answer your first bullet-point, I haven't submitted my Live Streaming app so I don't know for sure, but I believe you will be rejected if you don't have a 64k stream. To be sure, check out [Requirements for Apps](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008332-CH102-DontLinkElementID_20), which is as definitive a list of requirements that you could probably get.

Comment: So it appears that I don't have to do anything on the iPhone, if I'm directing the UIWebView to a .m3u8 file, am I correct?

Is the bandwidth issue server related?  File-related?

Comment: Dude, you answered this for me back in 2010.  :D