# Large files download: Throttle the bandwidth?

Tags: ios

I would like to know if it's still necessary to throttle the bandwidth when transferring multiples large files (PDF) over the cellular network.
There is no information about this in the guidelines but some old threads points out this was necessary.

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1130677.html

[iPhone app rejected for "transferring excessive volumes of data"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236788/iphone-app-rejected-for-transferring-excessive-volumes-of-data)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this only applies for streaming like mp3 data.

If you have a large single file which you need to download, throttling the bandwidth is an *especially bad* idea. The opposite would be recommend: download as fast as possible in order to safe battery and increase reliability of the connection (the shorter the duration the less the probability that it gets interrupted).

You should however check whether the connection uses the cellular network and notify the User and ask whether your app should defer the download when Wifi is available, possibly automatically in the background without starting the app. This approach is feasible (utilizing `NSURLSession`).